# C++ Libcurl: curl_easy_perform returned error code 28 when transferring files from linux system to windows remote system

Tags: c++, linux, ftp, libcurl

I’m using libcurl 7.37.0 in my C++ project to communicate with remote by FTP protocol.

below is the code.

```
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_URL, remoteFileUrl);
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, ON);

// Set the input local file handle
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_READDATA, localFileHandle);

// Set on/off all wanted options
// Enable ftp data connection
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, OFF);

// Create missing directory into FTP path
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS , ON) ;

// Set the progress function, in order to check the stop transfer request
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, OFF);
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, progressCb);
curl_easy_setopt(CurlSessionHandle, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, this);

CURLcode Result = curl_easy_perform(CurlSessionHandle);
```

many times i have observed uploading of files is failing due to **error code 28**.

**CURLE_OPERATION_TIMEDOUT (28)**
Operation timeout. The specified time-out period was reached according to the conditions.

i didn't set any timeout in the code, after doing a lot of search i came to know we can use **CURLOPT_TIMEOUT** to set the timeout value, by default it's value is 0 where it doesn't timeout until it finishes the respective operation, in my case i performed file upload operation.

after going through the wireshark logs, i have observed that when data transfer is initiated from port 20, i see libcurl sends **[FIN,ACK]** without any known reason to port 21, because of that remote sends response code 426(transfer aborted) to libcurl and it returns 28 error code to application.

Please check the image which has wireshark traces.

Source IP: 18 is Linux server & Destination IP: 36 is Windows remote system

[image]

This problem is happening randomly.
Could anyone know the reason & a way to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When this issue occurs, reset the curl context CurlSessionHandle and re initialize it. This might work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17926223)

Comment: @TheDictator Although this answer is not very detailed, it may contain a valid solution. Please do not recommend to delete this while there is no other answer.